# why routeline doesn't appear? xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, maps

This is my custom map (PCL)

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public List<Position> RouteCoordinates { get; set; }

    public CustomMap()
    {
        RouteCoordinates = new List<Position>();
    }
}
```

this is My View (PCL)

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ComoChegarView : ContentPage
{
    Localizacao userLocal;

    public ComoChegarView(double lat, double longi)
    {
        userLocal = new Localizacao();
        Task.Run(async () => await getUserLocal()).Wait();
        Localizacao lojaLocal =  new Localizacao();
        lojaLocal.latitude = lat;
        lojaLocal.longitude = longi;

        InitializeComponent();

        //route
        var customMap = new CustomMap
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
        };
             Content = customMap;

        customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(userLocal.latitude, userLocal.longitude));
        customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(lojaLocal.latitude, lojaLocal.longitude));
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(userLocal.latitude, userLocal.longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
    }
```

and this is my CustomMapRenderer (Android)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using neoFly_Montana;
using neoFly_Montana.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap map;
    List<Position> routeCoordinates;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            map = googleMap;

            var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

            foreach (var position in routeCoordinates)
            {
                polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
            }

            map.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


}
}
```

the OnMapReady is not called and I don't know why.
I am using xamarin.forms
the map works, only the line doesn't
Will it draw a line that follow the streets and turn correctly or do I need set the points where it should turn? 
I really need your answer

Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed your `OnMapReady` inside of the `OnElementChanged`? Is this a typo of your question? Try to get it out of `OnElementChanged`.

If the routeline doesn't show, it's possible that you didn't add the right key in Android's manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

To get this key, you may refer to the doc [Obtaining a Google Maps API Key](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/).

Comment: The key is right, because the map is running perfectly, but now I will try it you said me. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are sure, it didn't appear because the method that that was inside the other. Now it draw the paths...Do you know if there is a way to do it turn the streets automatically? Or do I need to set it point by point always? Because now it draws a rect line that doesn't respect the streets draw.
Thanks

Comment: @JoycedeLanna, to turn the streets automatically, in your PCL when create a new instance of this custom map, constraint `MapType` for example: `var customMap = new CustomMap{IsShowingUser = true,MapType = MapType.Street,.......}`